# How To Display My Invoice Data In Invoice Template

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

I have invoices table, i need to display specific invoice in a new component, so user can see whatever invoice he wants or print that invoice.

I don't know how to do that, i'm just playing around, if you could help me out, i'll be very grateful to you.

**`<router-link>` to the component**

```html
<router-link to="/ct-invoice-view" @click="openInvoice(ctInvoice)">
  <i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg text-blue"></i>
</router-link>
```

**Displaying `Customer` information here like this:**

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
  <address v-for="ctInvoice in ctInvoices" :key="ctInvoice.id">
     <strong>Customer Info</strong><br>
     Name: <span>{{ ctInvoice.customer.customer_name }}</span>
```

**Invoice view component `data()` & `method{}`**

```js
data() {
    return {
      ctInvoices: {},
      customers: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openInvoice(ctInvoice) {
      axios
        .get("api/ct-invoice/show/" + this.viewInvoice)
        .then(({
          data
        }) => (this.ctInvoices = data.data));
    },
```

**Image for Better Understanding**
[image]

Comment: I am unsure of the ask here. Can you create a simple jsFiddle with sample data and post it?

Comment: i don't know about Fiddie, i just need to view my invoice, like when i click on view button, that specific invoice detail should display.... @SujilMaharjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MarcNewton

I did something like this, it's working for me, can u just review it for me:

**`<router-link>` to the Invoice View component**

```html
<router-link v-bind:to="{name: 'ctInvoiceView', params: {id: ctInvoice.id}}">
  <i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg text-blue"></i>
</router-link>
```

**Getting Data of Specific Invoice ID Like This:**

```js
created: function() {
  axios
    .get("/api/ct-invoice/" + this.$route.params.id)
    .then(({
      data
    }) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.form = new Form(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
},
```

Comment: Since you are working with Laravel, You do not need to use From data objects.
JSON is native to Laravel. For example in InvoiceController@show($id) you can do: return Invoice::findOrFail($id).
In axios .then(response => { console.log(response.data) }).

Comment: When posting axios.post(URI, this.form).... is sufficient, the native raw javascript object will be posted as JSON by default and Laravel will handle that out of the box, Laravels $request->input will have parsed the posted object as if it was a Form object that was posted, this will make your code a little more streamlined.
No need to JSON encode or decode anything...

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at Dynamic Route matching: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Then you need to use **axios.get** in invoice views **beforeMount** function where **this.$route.params.id** will hold the invoice ID you want to load if the link is applied like so:

```
<router-link :to="`/ct-invoice-view/${ctInvoice.id}`">
  <i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg text-blue"></i>
</router-link>
```

Alternatively...

I suggest not navigating away from the list, it can be irritating for users having filtered the list then returning to it to look at more invoices and having to filter again unless the filter options and current results are sticky

There are a number of ways of doing this and they are lengthy to example, Typically I would make proper use of a [modal](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html) and the invoice view load the data on display but to get you started a basic in page solution to experiment with, then try adapting in a reusable modal component later:

```
<button @click="showInvoice = ctInvoice.id">
  <i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg text-blue"></i>
</button>
```

---

```
data() {
    return {
        loading: false,
        invoice: {},
        customers: null
    };
},
computed: {
    showInvoice: {
        get: function() {
            return this.invoice.hasOwnProperty('id');
        },
        set: function(value) {

            if(value === false) {
                this.invoice = {};
                return;
            }

            // could check a cache first and push the cached item into this.invoice else load it:

            this.loading = true;

            axios.get("api/ct-invoice/show/" + value).then(response => {
                 // you could push the invoice into a cache
                this.invoice = response.data;

            }).cache(error => {
                // handle error
            }).finally(() => {
                this.loading = false;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

In view-invoice component have a close button with bind **@click="$emit('close')"**
Check this article for how $emit works: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

```
<div v-if="loading" class="loading-overlay"></div>
<view-invoice v-if="showInvoice" :invoice="invoice" @close="showInvoice = false" />
<table v-else>....</table>
```

Hide the table when displaying the invoice, experiment with using v-show instead of v-if upon loosing table content state.

Inside your invoice view, property called invoice will contain the invoice data.
Check this article for how to use props: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

> Hint: The @close listens to the $emit('close')

Could also make use of  when switching between table and invoice view.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html